High-Frequency Background Events and Invalid Battery Level in capacitor-background-geolocation on Specific Samsung Devices
I'm using the capacitor-background-geolocation plugin to track background location updates in my app. The app works fine on most devices, but I’ve noticed unusual behavior on specific Samsung devices. Here’s the problem:

Excessive Background Events: On these devices, background events like providerchange, motionchange, and location are sent to the server at an extremely high rate—4-5 times per second. This happens even though the expected behavior is a maximum of 30 updates per hour.

Invalid Battery Level: For these excessive updates, the battery.level field always reports -21474836, while extras.batteryLevel provides a valid value (e.g., 0.82 for 82%).

Specific Devices Affected:


Samsung Galaxy A50s (SM-A5070)
Samsung Galaxy A53 5G (SM-A536E)
Samsung Galaxy S22 5G (SM-S901E)
Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G (SM-G7810)
Samsung Galaxy S10 SM (SM-G973F)
Samsung Galaxy A80 (SM-A805N)
Samsung Galaxy A90 5G (SM-A908N)
Samsung Galaxy S10 5G (SM-G977B)

Unique Pattern: For updates with battery.level as -21474836, the activity field always shows

"activity": {
   "type": "still",
   "confidence": 100
}

Plugin Configuration
await BackgroundGeolocation.ready({
  autoSync: true,
  debug: false,
  desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.DESIRED_ACCURACY_NAVIGATION,
  distanceFilter: 200,
  elasticityMultiplier: 4,
  extras: {
    androidSDKVersion: 32,
    appVersion: "3.4.3"
  },
  headers: {
    ContentType: "application/json"
  },
  isMoving: true,
  logLevel: BackgroundGeolocation.LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
  reset: true,
  showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: false,
  startOnBoot: true,
  stationaryRadius: 25,
  stopOnTerminate: false,
  stopTimeout: 5,
  url: "https://your-server-url.com",
  useSignificantChangesOnly: true
});

What I’ve Tried:

I’ve verified the app configuration and confirmed that these
behaviors occur only on the specific Samsung devices listed above.

The issue does not appear on other Android or iOS devices, even with
the same app version and configuration.


Questions

Could there be something in the plugin’s handling of background events (providerchange, motionchange, location) that interacts differently with these specific devices?
What could cause battery.level to consistently report -21474836 on these devices while extras.batteryLevel remains valid?
Are there any configuration changes I can make to minimize redundant events or address this behavior?
Could the unique activity pattern (type: "still", confidence: 100) provide a clue as to what’s causing these excessive updates?

Any suggestions or insights into this behavior would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if additional details or logs would help!

you have a paid plugin, why not write this in  the github repo issues section? the owner always helps. on another note, this plugin is highly documented. you need to look at the docs becuase all that your asking have the answers there.

as for the excessive updates, theres a parameter in the BackgroundGeolocation.ready that handles these updates. seems your getting issues is because you have several params on the ready method thats making that excessiveness occur.

@StackOverHoes
I’ve thoroughly reviewed the documentation and believe I’ve implemented everything correctly, which is why it works on about 90% of devices. However, I’m encountering the above error on specific devices only. Do you have any suggestions to resolve this?
I’ve also created a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/transistorsoft/capacitor-background-geolocation/issues/298
